# Uploadfive(html5) - Internet Explorer 9 not working

Tags: internet-explorer-9, uploadify, uploadifive

I have integrated Uploadfive(html5) in my project and its working Good in Firefox, Chrome and Safari. But, it fails to work in IE 9.

Let me know the solution/patch to include in the project, inorder to make it work in IE 9 as well.

Waiting for the Successful solution.

Comment: It does not sound as if you have made any attempt to solve this.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes, i have made an attempt and included in the demo but when check in the IE version it fails to load and then in search for the solution

Answer (score 1):

UploadiFive is for HTML 5 browsers that support the HTML 5 file API.

IE 9 does not support the HTML 5 File API. The first version of IE that does is IE 10.

Use the older (and free)  `uploadify` instead on older browsers. It uses a flash plugin to do the same job.

Unfortunately the API of uploadify and uploadifive are very slightly different so you need two lots of code *(we wound up wrapping both in our own JQuery plugin which chooses between them, based on browser capabilities, and modifies a single set of options & HTML templates to suit. Worth doing if you have loads of sites needing this).*

You can include both uploadify and uploadifive in the same page, just choose between them with the following test:

```
   if (window.FormData !== undefined) 
   { 
        // use uploadifive 
   } 
   else 
   {
        // use uploadify 
   }
```

Comment: HI, thanks for info.

Can i merge both flash and html5 and set any condition about browser type and bind as appropriate?

Comment: Include both plugins and call one or the other based on this test `if (window.FormData !== undefined) { use uploadifive } else { use uploadify }` I will add this to the answer